# npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT When I Want Install node_modules with docker-compose

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm using Dockerfile to run and install node_modules for a gatsby project. The `Dockerfile` has the below structure:

```
FROM node:alpine

EXPOSE 8000

RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base python3-dev python3 libffi-dev libressl- 
 dev bash git gettext curl \
 && curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py \
 && python3 get-pip.py \
 && pip install --upgrade six awscli awsebcli

WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN yarn install && yarn cache clean

CMD ["yarn", "develop", "-H", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

And Here is the code of `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - app/node_modules
      - .:/app
```

After running `docker-compose build` command  I'm getting the below error:
[image]

How can I solve this problem and install node_modules with docker?

Comment: It looks like you attached an image to the question; is this the response from an HTTP request, or what code produces that image?  Is there a text-format error you meant to include instead?  You have `volumes:` that replace everything in the image with different content, does removing those resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Usually these problems are related to internet Censorship.
Run this command `docker container prune` and `docker image prune`
Then use a proxy.
These commands remove cached and useless containers and images. But be careful if you have an important image or container.